# JPQL Query between dates using Calendar

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, calendar, jpql

I am having troubles making a query to extract all data from a single day.

This are my Calendar objects:

```
2018-04-13T00:00:00.000Z//Fri Apr 13 23:59:59 CEST 2018
2018-04-15T00:00:00.000Z//Sun Apr 15 00:00:00 CEST 2018
```

This is my named query:

```
select count(u) from EntityPoll u where pollId = :pollId and FUNCTION('TRUNC', u.requestDate) > :startDate and FUNCTION('TRUNC', u.requestDate) < :endDate
```

This is my hibernate generated sql **(return 0 elements)**:

```
select count(entitypoll0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from NEOL_ES_POLL entitypoll0_ 
where entitypoll0_.POLL_ID=? 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE)>? 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE)<?
```

This is the same query, but executed in SQL Developer **(5 results, ok)**:

```
select count(entitypoll0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from NEOL_ES_POLL entitypoll0_
where entitypoll0_.POLL_ID=1500541052868 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE) > TO_DATE('2018-04-13','yyyy-MM-dd') 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE) < TO_DATE('2018-04-15','yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Any way, this last query have 2 to_Date objects replacing my calendar objects, but I can't find the difference of results with this.

My Dao:

```
Query q = createNamedQuery(EntityPoll.SELECT_BY_POLLID);
        q.setParameter("pollId", pollId);
        q.setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE);
        q.setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
        try {
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

This my data's table:

```
2141777690  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777750  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777810  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777870  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777930  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141778470  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141778590  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141778980  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141779010  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141779100  1500541052868   13/04/18
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , can be wrong but , one thing in your code keeps me thinking . While you are setting parameter and passing `to_date` in oracle but not when you are passing the parameter like `to_date(?, 'dd-mm-yyyy')`. The first parameter here is string. As for the differences , i am not the fan of way you are doing. Thanks